# Transfer contents from C FILE to C++ stream

Tags: c++, file-io, ostream

Suppose I have a file opened with the C syntax

```
FILE* fp = fopen("whatever.txt", "w");
// Library function needs FILE* to work on
libray_function(fp);

// Now I'd like to copy the contents of file to std::cout
// How???

fclose(fp);
```

I would like to be able to copy the contents of that file in a C++ ostream (like a `stringstream` or maybe even `std::cout`). How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with `fread` and putting the data into a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close it first.

```
fclose(fp);
```

Then open again

```
string line;
ifstream myfile ("whatever.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
        getline (myfile,line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: This is C++ and you certainly almost never need/want to use `is_open`, `good` or `close`, neither did the OP say anything about line-based data. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/743214).

Comment: Hmm.... thanks. i see. He is not asking line based data...

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and [`rdbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

std::ifstream in("whatever.txt");
std::ostringstream s;
s << in.rdbuf();
```

or:

```
std::ifstream in("whatever.txt");
std::cout << in.rdbuf();
```

Comment: @PiotrNycz, yes. Is there a reason you think it won't?

Comment: I thought it only works for stringstream's where all contents is in streambuf. For filebuf I believe it is not common to have in buffer let say entire 1GB file... But I did not try. Just curious you have any link describing this `os << buf` operator?

Comment: @PiotrNycz, you may find this useful: http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/libstdc++-2.90.8/html/27_io/howto.html

Comment: I was wrong - ignore my comment/request. +1 for that was an opportunity to read the right chapter from the standard.

Comment: Thanks - I was writing my last comment without seeing your last one.

Answer (score 1):

You've opened the file for write. You're going to need to close it and reopen it anyway, you might as well open it however you please (as an istream if you like). Then it just depends how much you care about performance. If you actually care, you should read it in chunks (at least 512 bytes at a time). If you don't care about performance you can read one byte, spit out one byte.